# Value of lastrowid after "insert or ignore"

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, insert

I am using sqlite, and I have a `Python` code as follows:

```
...
cur.execute("insert or ignore into books (title, authors, ...) \
values (:title, :authors, ..."), locals())
...
bookId = cur.lastrowid
```

If the `ignore` part of the `select statement` applies

then the value of `cur.lastrowid` is `0`.

But this is not what I want. I'd like to get `books.id` value from the database
in any case.

Should I use `select` statement or is there smarter way to achieve it?

My temporary solution:

```
if bookId == 0:
    cur.execute("select id from books where \
    title = :title and authors = :authors", locals())
    bookId = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no better way.
To read some *existing* value from the database, there's only `SELECT`.

Comment: I believe you because of your reputation :-) Thanks

Comment: I'm amazed there's no better way. Seems pretty effin dumb to have to do an extra select, frankly.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `on duplicate key update id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` for the PK. Seems like lastrowID will be correct from then on out.

Comment: This is for mysql not sqlite. As far as i know there is no such option in sqlite. The equivalent of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in sqlite `last_insert_rowid()` doesn't take any arguments and cannot set the last insert id.

Comment: Only tags said anything about sqlite, that should have been specified in the question text. I edited the question to include this just now

Comment: Not sure that is the proper way to go. They are obviously asking for sqlite as they mention `lastrowid`. Also the examples in the question include sqlite. This is just gonna lead people to try this answer for sqlite and fail.

Comment: MySQL python connector uses the name `lastrowid` too. It's not so obviously sqlite.